# find duplicates in a xml page

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to find duplicates within the xml returned by a web service call using ruby and nokogiri.

The output that i'm getting from the code below is something like this:

```
found duplicate["1", "1"]
found duplicate["1", "1"]
found duplicate["1", "1"]
found duplicate["1", "1"]
found duplicate["2", "2"]
```

What I want to know is that skus 1 and 2 have been duplicated. So something like this "found duplicate skus [Duplicated skus]."

the xml is like this:

```
<Root>
  <Context>
  <ID>1234</ID> 
<Item>
  <ID>4567</ID> 
  </Item>
<Item>
  <ID>4567</ID> 
</Item>
<Item>
  <ID>5678</ID> 
</Item>
```

```
#Context Items that will produce duplicates. 
$context = ['a','b','c']

#Class that will search through an array to find duplicates
class Array
  def only_duplicates
  duplicates = []
  self.each {|each| duplicates << each if self.count(each) > 1}
  duplicates
 end
end

#loops through each item in the $context array
 $context.each do |item|
 puts "C_ItemID = " + item
 #Creates a url string using the context item
url = "url to the call"
#Creates a xml doc
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))
    #Declare a blank array that the text from the node will be stored in
    values = []
    #loops through each item_id node to find duplicates. 
    doc.xpath('//item/id').each do |node|
        values << node.text
        @values = values.to_a
        if @values.only_duplicates.count > 1
            puts "found duplicate" + @values.only_duplicates.inspect
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
downloaded_from_url = "<Root><Context><ID>1234</ID><Item><ID>4567</ID></Item><Item><ID>4567</ID></Item><Item><ID>5678</ID></Item><Item><ID>5678</ID></Item>"
parsed_xml_document = Nokogiri::XML(downloaded_from_url)

list_of_item_ids    = parsed_xml_document.xpath("//Item/ID").map { |x| x.text }

def find_duplicate_items( in_collection=[] )
  in_collection.select do |item|
    in_collection.count(item) > 1
  end.uniq
end

duplicate_item_ids  = find_duplicate_items( list_of_item_ids )
#=> ["4567", "5678"]
```

A faster way to find duplicates(Credits: Ryan LeCompte). A slightly modified & shorter version.

```
def fast_find_duplicate_items ( in_collection=[] )
  collection.group_by do |element|
    element
  end.select do |key, value|
    value.size > 1
  end.keys
end
```

Comment: @Hillary Added a faster method for finding duplicate items.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more efficient way to find duplicates in an array (using #count makes the algorithm slower because it has to traverse the whole array for each item, O(N^2)):

```
list_of_item_ids.group_by { |e| e }.select { |k,v| v.size > 1 }.map(&:first)
```